# remap "undo key" to no op

Tags: key-bindings, macvim

I have a keyboard with an undo key right next to the esc key. I often miss esc, hit undo, which causes the vim process to be stopped. How can I remap the undo key in vim such that it doesn't do anything? I know how to map keys in vim, but I can't make it work for this particular key.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the character(s) that this key sends by using `<C-v>[key]` in commandline or insert mode; for example `<C-v><F1>`.

This will probably be multiple characters starting with the escape character (`^[`). You can then map this to `<Nop>`:

```
nnoremap <Esc>OP OP <Nop>
```

This example is F1 on my system.

Replace `^[` with `<Esc>`; you can also use the literal escape character, but that can be a bit awkward to edit.